# useEffect not triggering correctly when used with dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any better solution to this when the first useEffect fires, only getAccountDetailsData() will be successful, getErrorLogInfo() will fail because store.AccountDetails.ID is null at that stage. getAccountDetailsData() will get that value.

Now the use effect does not fire again, but waits 60 seconds to fire the 2nd one which fires every minute. and then everything works fine.

The problem is that I have to wait 1 minutes before I get getErrorLogInfo() to work.
if I put a dependency list [] in the first useEffect() it will fire in loops. I won't have to wait for 1 minute but it will trigger a 429 error

```
  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getAccountDetailsData(user.EmailAddress)); // we call this to get AccountDetails.ID
      dispatch(getErrorLogInfo(store.AccountDetails.ID)); // will not work missing AccountDetails.ID
  }, []); // I can put dependency list [] but will be endless loop


//now I have to wait 60 seconds to try again

  useEffect(() => {
    
      dispatch(getAccountDetailsData(user.EmailAddress)); works
      dispatch(getErrorLogInfo(store.AccountDetails.ID)); works
    }, 60000);// refresh data after every 60 seconds
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [store]);
```

Comment: What is `store`? A redux store?

Comment: I think you're going to need to paste your full component code in  here because there's a lot missing from this to help you with your statement.

Comment: I think the title of the question is misleading, `useEffect` is triggering exactly how it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put a guard statement on your `useEffect` callback to prevent it from attempting to `getErrorLogInfo` before `store.AccountDetails.ID` is set.

Also split up to using two `useEffect` statements since they will have different dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user?.EmailAddress) // checks if it exists before running the dispatch
    dispatch(getAccountDetailsData(user.EmailAddress));
}, [user?.EmailAddress]) // gets called once upon mount and if `user.EmailAddress` changes

useEffect(() => {
  if (store?.AccountDetails?.ID) // checks if it exists before running the dispatch
    dispatch(getErrorLogInfo(store.AccountDetails.ID))
}, [store?.AccountDetails?.ID]) // gets called once upon mount and if `user.EmailAddress` changes
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch data depending on store data u can do it with 2 `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getAccountDetailsData(user.EmailAddress));
}, [])
 
useEffect(()=>{
if(store.AccountDetails){ 
   dispatch(getErrorLogInfo(store.AccountDetails.ID));
  }
},[store.AccountDetails])
```

Comment: `store.AccountDetails` is risky since there are a number of unknowns that could cause problems with this e.g. is it instantiated already as part of the store init? Does the reducer completely overwrite that slice when it's then set? Safer to just check explicitly for the ID (see @BarryMichaelDoyle's answer)